# Libgdx UI using Scene2d.ui -does it work on iOS?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, libgdx, scene2d

I want to create a simple game for Android and iOS primarily using libgdx.

The game is going to need UI in the form of text input fields and
buttons.

Now, there is a package called Scene2d.ui which has for instance the class TextField.
However, it says in the javadoc (which might be old, because some other stuff lying around is) that:

"Currently there are two standard implementations, one for the desktop and one for Android."

Does this mean (in current version) that there is no standard (cross-platform) libgdx package for doing ui that covers both Android and iOS and Desktop (and everything), so that I don't have to make one ui per platform?

If I use ui from Scene2d, will it not work for iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scene2d works fine with IOS. We are using scene2d to build UIs and robovm for porting the game to IOS.
Classes under the core gdx project should work on all platforms. Platform specific codes are in backend projects (ie android backend, robovm backend...)

So in short, Scene2d works perfectly on IOS.

Comment: I am having big problems with the soft keyboard (on mobile devices) obscuring textfields. Have you managed to solve those UI problems?